# Maximize the volume of a rectangular box in the first octant with one vertex in the plane $x+2y+3z=3$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Find the volume of the largest rectangular box in the first octant with the three faces in the coordinate planes and one vertex in the plane $x+2y+3z=3$.

Now I know that $V=xyz$ and I have set $$V=xy\left(1-\frac{x}{3}-\frac{2y}{3}\right).$$
After I take the partial derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$, I am not sure what to do. Any help would be great! Thanks.

Comment: Next you want to set $V_{x}$ and $V_{y}$ equal to 0, and then multiply through by 3 and factor each equation, keeping in mind that $x>0$ and $y>0$

Comment: Well I did and solved for the variable but it is still wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $V=xy-\frac{1}{3}x^2y-\frac{2}{3}xy^2$,

$V_{x}=y-\frac{2}{3}xy-\frac{2}{3}y^2=0$ and $V_{y}=x-\frac{1}{3}x^2-\frac{4}{3}xy=0$.

Multiplying by 3 in each equation and dividing by $y$ in the first equation and by $x$ in the second equation (since $x>0$ and $y>0$) gives

$2x+2y=3$ and $x+4y=3$.  (Now solve for x and y.)

Answer (score 0):

Build the Lagrangian

$$\mathcal{L} (x,y,z,\lambda) = x y z + \lambda (x + 2 y + 3 z - 3)$$

Take the $4$ partial derivatives and find where they vanish. Subtracting the equations in order to eliminate $\lambda$, one obtains

$$(x-2y) \, z = 0 \qquad \qquad (x-3z) \, y = 0$$

As $y = 0$ and $z = 0$ yield a box of zero volume, they are not admissible. From $x = 2 y$ and $x = 3z$, one obtains the parametrization of the line that intersects the given plane at the desired vertex of the box of maximal volume.